# How to generate a large (30MB+) xml file in java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, stream, scalability

The file itself is not that big, should fit in memory. But once you combine that with other overhead factors then starts to become a problem. We are building a DOM in memory and that is not scaling for us. Using raw output streams seems problematic in the sense that we have to be careful about escaping characters.

What are some good approaches for doing this?

Are there any goods libs for this?

Comment: you are absolutely right NOT to write your own XML serializer, there is plenty of good ones around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

STAX provides a convenient API with which to write XML to output stream. Easy tutorial [here](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1287).

Comment: +1 - though it looks like you need to be cautious with StAX, because it is easier (than a DOM / DOM-like library) to generate malformed or nonsensical XML.

Comment: Example link is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

### Features

- Ease of use. A high level facade is supplied that simplifies common use cases.
- No mappings required. Most objects can be serialized without need for specifying mappings.
- Performance. Speed and low memory footprint are a crucial part of the design, making it suitable for large object graphs or systems with high message throughput.
- Clean XML. No information is duplicated that can be obtained via reflection. This results in XML that is easier to read for humans and more compact than native Java serialization.
- Requires no modifications to objects. Serializes internal fields, including private and final. Supports non-public and inner classes. Classes are not required to have default constructor.
- Full object graph support. Duplicate references encountered in the object-model will be maintained. Supports circular references.
- Integrates with other XML APIs. By implementing an interface, XStream can serialize directly to/from any tree structure (not just XML).
- Customizable conversion strategies. Strategies can be registered allowing customization of how particular types are represented as XML.
- Error messages. When an exception occurs due to malformed XML, detailed diagnostics are provided to help isolate and fix the problem.
- Alternative output format. The modular design allows other output formats. XStream ships currently with JSON support and morphing.

Comment: XStream looks like a good serialization lib but since I don't have an object representation for this particular feed it doesn't seem to apply. But thanks I will definitely take a look at this for other projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With Saxon, you can use the StAX XMLStreamWriter API in conjunction with a Serializer that gives you full control of the serialization properties as defined in xsl:output, for example the ability to control indentation, use of CDATA sections, etc. See the s9api Serializer class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your data is structured, but a StAX implementation might be what you are looking for - like Woodstock for example.